# ReplaceText Usage in Apache NiFi

Tags: java, regex, apache-nifi

I am trying to make use of the out-of-the-box processor ReplaceText in Apache NiFi to search inside a .dsv file, match all datetime formats and convert them into dates. I am not sure, however, how to configure the processor itself. I have tried to set my search value (Search Value Property) to something like this:

```
(0{0,1}[1-9])|(1/d)|(2/d)|(3[0-1])/(0{0,1}[1-9])|(1[0-2])/([1-9]/d):(0{0,1}/d)|(1/d)|(2[0-4]):(0{0,1}/d)|([1-5]/d)
```

Whereas my Replacement Value is regex1 that matches to ${time:format("yyyy-MM-dd'")} I have also set up another property named time that in turns matches to     `(0{0,1}[1-9])|(1/d)|(2/d)|(3[0-1])/(0{0,1}[1-9])|(1[0-2])/([1-9]/d):(0{0,1}/d)|(1/d)|(2[0-4]):(0{0,1}/d)|([1-5]/d)`

This does not work and I have the feeling I am not using ReplaceText as it should be. Can you help?

EDIT:

I should have included that I am using the Replacement Strategy called Regex Replace and Evaluation Mode Entire text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe a similar question was answered on the Apache mailing list, for reference:

I created a template [1] that shows an example of how to do the date conversion you described. It is linked to from the main templates page on the wiki [2] and is named "DateConversion.xml"

It first uses ExtractText to find the date string and extract it into an attribute called "date". The regular expression used is: (\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2})

Then it uses ReplaceText with the Search Value of the same regular expression above, to replace that with ${date:toDate("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss"):format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+0000")}

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/57904847/DateConversion.xml?version=2&modificationDate=1462288576652&api=v2

[2] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Example+Dataflow+Templates

Comment: Bryan, yes I posted the question to the NiFi malingList too, thank you so much for both of your replies. I have tried out your template and does work as expected. Thank you!!!